# Filtering and summarizing but keeping 'zeros'

Tags: r

I have data collected at a number of Sites. At each site, species were identified (Species) and counted (Number). I also recorded teh distance they occurred from me (Distance). A sample data set is:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

Data <- data.frame(
  Site = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "3", "3"),
  Species = c("abc", "bcd", "abc", "kjh", "jh", "abc", "gd"),
  Number = c(10,1,1,1,1,1,1),
  Distance = c("50m", "60m", "In", "In", "Out", "In", "In")
)
```

I wish to calculate: (A) the number of unique species and (B) the number of individuals of each Species at each Site. However, I wish to filter out all Distances == "Out". I tried the following filter:

```
Filtered <- Data %>%
  filter(Distance %in% c(
    "50m", 
    "60m",
    "In"))
```

And then created my summary:

```
summary <- Filtered %>%
  group_by(Site) %>% 
  summarize(richness = n_distinct(Species), count = sum(Number))
summary
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  Site  richness count
  <fct>    <int> <dbl>
1 1            3    13
2 3            2     2
```

But what I really need is:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Site  richness count
  <fct>    <int> <dbl>
1 1            3    13
2 2            0     0
3 3            2     2
```

In other words, I don't want the 'Out" sites to be included in the summary calculations, but I want to show that there were 0 species at the 'non-Out' Distances.

Is there a better way that I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could `group_by` `Site` and filter "Out" entries after grouping in `summarize` step.

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>%
  group_by(Site) %>%
  summarize(richness = n_distinct(Species[Distance != "Out"]), 
            count = sum(Number[Distance != "Out"]))


#  Site  richness count
#  <fct>    <int> <dbl>
#1 1            3    13
#2 2            0     0
#3 3            2     2
```